# IE response.redirect

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I ran into an extremely odd issue with IE today. IE fails every time I try to do a response.redirect more than ten times! Of course, the page works fine in FF and Chrome. Has anyone else experienced something like this?

Here are some code snippets to make sure I am not doing anything blatantly wrong...

### Loop

```
if ( iDomain < ubound(aDomain) ) then
    Response.Redirect "/home/login/a_logout.asp?site=" & strSite & "&domain=" & iDomain+1 & "&l=" & ilogout & "&s=" &sSid
end if
```

### Array

```
Dim aDomain(10)

aDomain(0) = ".x.com"
aDomain(1) = "www.x.com"
aDomain(2) = "w1.x.com"
aDomain(3) = "w2.x.com"
aDomain(4) = "x.com"
aDomain(5) = "w3.corporate.x.com"
'aDomain(5) = "w4.x.com"
aDomain(6) = "w5.x.com"
aDomain(7) = "w6.x.com"
'aDomain(8) = ""
'aDomain(9) = "w8.x.com"
aDomain(8) = "w9.x.com" 
aDomain(9) = "w10.x.com"
```

Removed context sensitive data.

Let me know if you need any other info. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behaviour to prevent a user from being looped back to the same page infinitely.

IE8s limit is 10 requests to the same page, Chrome and FireFox I believe are 20.

And no, a different querystring doesn't constitute a new page as I [found out myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441678/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-several-automatic-redirects).

Comment: Interesting... Is there a way to change it to 20 for a certain page? Or does that have to be set on the client's browser?

Comment: @Ant, it has to be set on the client browser. Check the link I added. I had the same problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest that you change this.  Redirecting multiple times is a pretty bad idea.

Instead, just run whatever code is being run by your a_logout page locally.  I'm assuming your clearing several cookies.  Go ahead and resend all of the appropriate cookies with blank data and an expires yesterday time.

Comment: It is poor architecture. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting so often *is* blatantly wrong. The ideal maximum number of redirects is 1. In practice it can be a lot easier to do certain tasks if you allow for more than that, but anywhere more than 5 redirects happen should be considered a bug (more than 1 on the same server or more than 3 that crosses to another server should be considered sub-optimal, but not urgent to fix).

Browsers can't depend upon servers never doing anything blatantly wrong, so after a few goes they give up to save the user from the server. Sometimes user-agents don't protect themselves in this way (not serious browsers, but it's an easy mistake to make writing a simple piece of HTTP client code). It isn't pretty.

To demonstrate just how bad this can be, consider a case where the handler for /somePath/?id=1 redirects to /somePath/?id=2 which redirects to /somePath/?id=3 and so on. For all the server knows, you've just got a more obscure version of that, and will never stop redirecting.